# How to get full name of month from date in Java 8 while formatting

Tags: java, localization, date-formatting, java-time

Using new Java 8 java.time API, I need to convert LocalDate and get full name of month and day. Like March (not Mar), and Monday (not Mon). Friday the 13th March should be formatted like Friday, 13 March.. not Fri, 13 Mar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The string you are looking for is `MMMM`.

Source: [DateTimeFormatter Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Thanks. How about full day?

Comment: Oh, and full day is EEEE! Got it from your javadoc. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant day of month, not day of week.

Answer (score 20):

## tl;dr

Use automatic localization. No need to specify formatting pattern.

```
localDate.format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
                     .withLocale( Locale.UK )
)
```

> Monday, 23 January 2017

```
LocalDate
.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
.getMonth()
.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL , 
    Locale.CANADA_FRENCH 
)
```

> janvier

## Month

Taking your title literally, I would use the handy [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
Month month = ld.getMonth() ;  // Returns a `Month` object, whereas `getMonthValue` returns an integer month number (1-12).
```

Let java.time do the work of automatically localizing. To localize, specify:

- [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

For example:

```
String output = month.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.KOREA, etc.
```

> janvier

## Date

If you want the entire date localized, let `DateTimeFormatter` do the work. Here we use [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) rather than `TextStyle`.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US, Locale.KOREA, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( l ) ;
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> dimanche 23 janvier 2107

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Some locale constants are not available. You can replace `Locale.UK` constant with new Locale("ru") then.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Now it can be done.

```
LocalDate dd = new LocalDate();  //pass in a date value or params(yyyy,mm)

String ss = dd.monthOfYear.getAsText(); // will give the full name of the month
String sh = dd.monthOfYear.getAsShortText(); // shortform
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

Just use the `getDayOfWeek()`

```
LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek().name()
```

You can use it as

```
public static String dayName(int month, int day, int year) {

    return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek().name();

}
```